# Print an 2D array to an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I'm building a 2D array in TypeScript. Here is my code in TypeScript.

```
this.boxArray = new Array<Array<Box>>();
const ROW_MAX: number = 10;
const COL_MAX: number = 10;

for (let i: number = 0; i < ROW_MAX; i++) {
  const row: Box[] = new Array<Box>();
  for (let j: number = 0; j < COL_MAX; j++) {
    row.push(new Box("A"));
  }
  this.boxArray.push(row);
}
```

I want to print it as a 10 by 10 table in HTML. It works when I use `<table>` and `<td>`, but if I want to use `<div>`, it doesn't work. It print 100 box only, but not 10 by 10.

```
<div class="CrosswordGridComponent" *ngFor="let row of boxArray; let i = index">
<div *ngFor="let col of boxArray; let j = index">
  <input id="{{i}}_{{j}}" type="text" maxLength="1" class="box"  
  [ngClass]="{ 
    'black': boxArray[i][j].isBlack()
  }" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because a `div` element is a **["block-level" element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)** and block-level elements render on a new line and are 100% the width of their parent element.

If you want to use `div` elements, but have `table` style output, you'll need to make sure that the `div` elements that represent your rows are styled as `table-row` and that your `div` elements that represent your cells are styled as `table-cell` and that the `div` that holds all of it is styled as: `table`.

Here's an example:

```css
.table { display:table; }
.row   { display:table-row; }
.cell  { display:table-cell; border:1px solid black; padding:3px; }
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Cell 1, Row 1</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 2, Row 1</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 3, Row 1</div>    
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Cell 1, Row 2</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 2, Row 2</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 3, Row 2</div>    
  </div>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Cell 1, Row 3</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 2, Row 3</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 3, Row 3</div>    
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. But the problem with using a table is that I can't fix the maxLength to 1. I'm doing a crossword generator with Angular 4 btw. Thank you for your time

Comment: @Mohamed-AliElakhrass But, you are putting `input` elements inside of each cell, right? So, what's the issue? Also, don't forget to mark as "the" answer.